# Hiding class namespace from plugin's extensions

Tags: plugin-development, customization, namespace

I'm developing a plugin using [this boilerplate](https://github.com/karannagupta/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate) and I designed it to be extensible. The boilerplate supports namespacing and uses it and namespaces are bind to folder structure. The extensible part is about loading a class from the extension and I want to require extension developers to:

1. check the existance of the class loader (namespace: `Plugin_Name\Inc\Admin`)
2. extend their class from a base class (namespace: `Plugin_Name\Inc\Admin`)

I'm looking for the easiest way to fulfill the above so that they won't get involved with my plugin's namespaces.

Comment: Isn't the class loader located in `wp-plugin-name/inc/core/class-loader.php
`? Checking for a class is done with ie. `class_exists`, and extending a class is done with `extends`, so what is the actual problem?

Comment: i don't want to hide namespaces. for example `class_exists` works with just class name and without namespaces prefix or some design pattern technique to implement

Comment: Okay, so developers would use your class loader with ie `use Plugin_Name\Inc\Admin\ClassLoader` and the base class with `use Plugin_Name\Inc\Admin\BaseClass`. To extend the class, they could then `class NewClass extends BaseClass`.

Comment: sorry i was rewriting the comment and made a mistake:
i **want** to hide namespaces. for example class_exists works with just class name and without namespaces prefix or some design pattern technique to implement

Comment: If a class is defined within a namespace, it can only be accessed through that namespace, as far as I know. It's the point of the whole concept, to avoid conflicts in naming.

Comment: It doesn't seem right to give developers namespaces. can you guide me to change my plugin's structure to be more "extension friendly".

Comment: Namespaces are common among developers, and it's just as common to use the `use` statement if you want to implement a specific library. "It doesn't seem right to give developers namespaces." > Why is that?